# How to disable pushstate for Chrome? (for Davis.js)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pushstate

How do you disable pushstate for Chrome (for testing purposes)?

Bonus if you know of a plugin that makes it easy to toggle :)

*I'm using [davis.js](http://davisjs.com/) for my pushstate logic*.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable" and for what kind of testing? Event mechanisms are a native part of the browser, so js can't simply disable them, not in the meaning of "never letting them fire". If given further information about what testing you're doing, it may be possible to isolate the issue.

Comment: I'm trying to see what happens (emulate) when browsers that don't support pushstate hit my site. I'm using Davis.js for routing. I could just disable Davis from routing but that wouldn't be a fair test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your Davis.js routes are still working is because when you click a link it runs your routes directly, since there is no onPushState event, you should find though that using the back and forward buttons no longer trigger your routes.

If you want to emulate what happens in a browser that doesn't support pushState you can fool around with how Davis.js checks for support.  This is done in the [Davis.supported function](https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js/blob/master/lib/davis.js#L37-39).

You can override that function to always return false, which is what would happen normally in a browser that doesn't support pushState.  If you wanted to you could wrap this up into a Davis.js extension, see the [block iOS extension](https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js/blob/master/lib/extensions/davis.noiOS.js) as an example.

Comment: Thats what I ended up sort of doing. I'm really digging davis.

Comment: Glad its useful! You could probably wrap that behaviour into some kind of bookmarklet or chrome extension if you find yourself doing this regularly. Let me know if you do, I'll feature it on the Davis.js site.

Answer (score 3):

```
history.pushState = function (){};
//An empty function so if it is used, it doesn't throw any errors
```

Put that in the console. Tada! You can easily make a Chrome extension that executes that on a page using a Content Script.

Comment: I must be missing something because that does not work for me. My Davis.js routes are still being executed.